# golang convert iso8859-1 to utf8

Tags: character-encoding, go

I am trying to convert an ISO 8859-1 encoded string to UTF-8.

The following function works with my testdata which contains german umlauts, but I'm not quite sure what source encoding the rune(b) cast assumes. Is it assuming some kind of default encoding, e.g. ISO8859-1 or is there any way to tell it what encoding to use?

```
func toUtf8(iso8859_1_buf []byte) string {
   var buf = bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, len(iso8859_1_buf)*4))
   for _, b := range(iso8859_1_buf) {
      r := rune(b)
      buf.WriteRune(r)
   }
   return string(buf.Bytes())
}
```

Comment: By the way, you do mean iso8859-1, right?

Comment: yes, sorry about the confusion, I've edited it.

Comment: explicit conversion from iso-8859 encoded strings can be made by using golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap https://play.golang.org/p/D_lccJAqWtf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*rune* is an alias for *int32*, and when it comes to encoding, a rune is assumed to have a Unicode character value (code point). So the value `b` in `rune(b)` should be a unicode value. For 0x00 - 0xFF this value is identical to Latin-1, so you don't have to worry about it.

Then you need to encode the runes into UTF8. But this encoding is simply done by converting a `[]rune` to `string`.

This is an example of your function without using the bytes package:

```
func toUtf8(iso8859_1_buf []byte) string {
    buf := make([]rune, len(iso8859_1_buf))
    for i, b := range iso8859_1_buf {
        buf[i] = rune(b)
    }
    return string(buf)
}
```

Comment: I thought only values up to 0x7f were identical, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The values in Unicode and Latin-1 are identical (Latin-1 can be considered the 0x00 - 0xFF subset of Unicode). But when you store the value, Latin-1 uses only 1 byte (eg. `0x41`) while Unicode uses 4 bytes (eg. `0x00000041`). What might confuse is the UTF-8 encoding where only 0x00 - 0x7F are encoded in the same way as Latin-1, using a single byte.

Comment: It's not working https://play.golang.org/p/Ju2Te0kVUhE

Comment: @AdrienParrochia You have a 1) utf8-encoded string 2) decoded as latin1 3) copied to a Go byte slice where the faulty text is encoded as utf8 4) passed into a function that tries to reencode it as utf8. No. Just no :) . And during this, you've lost some data (shown by the unicode `?` placeholder character). You wanted something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/dBrx_ZmrsMN

Answer (score 2):

The effect of

```
r := rune(expression)
```

is:

- Declare variable `r` with type `rune` (alias for int32).
- Initialize variable `r` with the value of expresion.

No (re)encoding is involved and saying which one should be optionally used is possible only by explicitly writing/handling some re-encoding in code. Luckily, in this case no (re)encoding is necessary, Unicode incorporated those codes of ISO 8859-1 in a comparable way as ASCII. (If I checked correctly [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout))

Comment: Reencoding is needed. Letters like ö is not encoded in the same way. If you have the byte string `latin1 = []byte{0x52, 0xE4, 0x76}`, it will not convert well to string. (It says *Räv* in Latin-1)

Comment: But 0xE4 really is `ä`, not `ö` in ISO 8859-1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout. Check it here: http://play.golang.org/p/s4TfzJUa7m

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood. True that no reencoding is needed between Latin-1 and Unicode. Yes, the byte sequence says Räv

Answer (score 0):

To convert between any of the ISO-8859 variants (and other popular legacy code pages) and UTF-8 use [golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap).

To decode this latin1 encoding:

```golang
// rivière, è latin1-encoded as 233 (0xe9)
bLatin1 := []byte{114, 105, 118, 105, 233, 114, 101}
```

the Charmap type has a NewDecoder method that returns a *encoding.Decoder:

```golang
dec8859_1 := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder()
```

This decoder can decode bytes directly:

```golang
bUTF8, _ := dec8859_1.Bytes(bLatin1)

fmt.Printf("% #x\n", bLatin1) // 0x72 0x69 0x76 0x69 0xe9 0x72 0x65
fmt.Printf("% #x\n", bUTF8)   // 0x72 0x69 0x76 0x69 0xc3 0xa9 0x72 0x65
```

If you have file with a legacy encoding:

```golang
f, _ := os.Create("foo.txt")
f.Write(bLatin1)
f.Write([]byte("\n"))
f.Write([]byte("Seine"))
```

use the decoder to wrap your file's Reader:

```golang
f, _ = os.Open("foo.txt")
rLatin1 := dec8859_1.Reader(f)
```

and pass the new decoder-Reader:

```golang
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(rLatin1)

for i := 1; scanner.Scan(); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("line %d: %s\n", i, scanner.Text())
}
// line 1: riviére
// line 2: Seine
```