How to avoid improper view updates with Bubble Tea TUI
I have been working on adding a TUI to a Golang CLI application I use which can be found here. The main problem I am hitting is that whenever I start moving over the options for the suggestions to accept, ignore, edit, etc., I am getting incorrect text on the screen for the text I originally tried to print. I believe this is because the text in question has ANSI colors in it and it can be long at times. I also believe the issue is something about the way I am using nested models and the Update methods on them. However despite clearing the screen and trying other mechanism to get rid of the old text before printing the content of the next view. I am still seeing the issue.
Here is the relevant code from the repo:
The TUI entrypoint:
...
var (
            initialModel = NewFixableTuiModel(runAll, runSectionBreak, potentiallyFixableIssues, cssFiles)
            i            = 0
        )
        initialModel.filePaths = make([]string, len(epubInfo.HtmlFiles))

        // Collect file contents
        for file := range epubInfo.HtmlFiles {
            var filePath = getFilePath(opfFolder, file)
            zipFile := zipFiles[filePath]

            fileText, err := filehandler.ReadInZipFileContents(zipFile)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }

            initialModel.fileTexts[filePath] = linter.CleanupHtmlSpacing(fileText)
            initialModel.filePaths[i] = filePath
            i++
        }

        p := tea.NewProgram(&initialModel, tea.WithAltScreen())
        finalModel, err := p.Run()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        model := finalModel.(FixableTuiModel)
        if model.Err != nil {
            return nil, model.Err
        }
    ...

The main TUI model that wraps the other models:
package epub

import (
    "fmt"

    tea "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea"
    "github.com/pjkaufman/go-go-gadgets/ebook-lint/cmd/epub/tui"
)

type FixableTuiModel struct {
    currentStage                                        stage
    currentFile                                         string
    sectionBreakInput                                   tui.SectionBreakModel
    suggestionHandler                                   tui.SuggestionsModel
    potentiallyFixableIssues                            []potentiallyFixableIssue
    filePaths                                           []string
    fileTexts                                           map[string]string
    currentFilePathIndex, currentSuggestIndex           int
    cssFiles, handledFiles                              []string
    runAll, addCssSectionIfMissing, addCssPageIfMissing bool
    Err                                                 error
}

type stage int

const (
    sectionContextBreak stage = iota
    suggestionsProcessing
    stageCssSelection
    finalStage
)

func NewFixableTuiModel(runAll, runSectionBreak bool, potentiallyFixableIssues []potentiallyFixableIssue, cssFiles []string) FixableTuiModel {
    var startingStage = sectionContextBreak
    if !runAll && !runSectionBreak {
        startingStage = suggestionsProcessing
    }

    var input = tui.NewSectionBreakModel()

    return FixableTuiModel{
        sectionBreakInput:        input,
        currentStage:             startingStage,
        potentiallyFixableIssues: potentiallyFixableIssues,
        fileTexts:                make(map[string]string),
        cssFiles:                 cssFiles,
        runAll:                   runAll,
    }
}

func (f FixableTuiModel) Init() tea.Cmd {
    return nil
}

func (f FixableTuiModel) Update(msg tea.Msg) (tea.Model, tea.Cmd) {
    var cmd tea.Cmd

    if f.Err != nil {
        return f, tea.Quit
    }

    switch f.currentStage {
    case sectionContextBreak:
        if f.sectionBreakInput.Err != nil {
            f.Err = f.sectionBreakInput.Err

            return f, tea.Quit
        }

        f.sectionBreakInput, cmd = f.sectionBreakInput.Update(msg)
        f = f.advanceStageIfNeeded()

        return f, cmd
    case suggestionsProcessing:
        if f.suggestionHandler.Err != nil {
            f.Err = f.suggestionHandler.Err

            return f, tea.Quit
        }

        f.suggestionHandler, cmd = f.suggestionHandler.Update(msg)
        f = f.advanceStageIfNeeded()

        return f, cmd
    }

    return f, cmd
}

func (f FixableTuiModel) View() string {
    switch f.currentStage {
    case sectionContextBreak:
        return f.sectionBreakInput.View()
    case suggestionsProcessing:
        return f.suggestionHandler.View()
    }

    return ""
}

func (f FixableTuiModel) advanceStageIfNeeded() FixableTuiModel {
    switch f.currentStage {
    case sectionContextBreak:
        if f.sectionBreakInput.Done {
            contextBreak = f.sectionBreakInput.Value()
            f.currentStage = suggestionsProcessing
            f = f.getNextSuggestion()
        }
    case suggestionsProcessing:
        if f.suggestionHandler.Done {
            if f.currentFilePathIndex+1 < len(f.filePaths) {
                f = f.getNextSuggestion()

                return f
            }

            f.currentStage = stageCssSelection
            f.Err = fmt.Errorf("Not implemented stage yet")
            // TODO: figure out how to close the program
        }
    }

    return f
}

func (f FixableTuiModel) getNextSuggestion() FixableTuiModel {
    for f.currentFilePathIndex+1 < len(f.filePaths) {
        for f.currentSuggestIndex+1 < len(f.potentiallyFixableIssues) {
            var (
                currentFilePath = f.filePaths[f.currentFilePathIndex]
                suggestions     = f.potentiallyFixableIssues[f.currentSuggestIndex].getSuggestions(f.fileTexts[currentFilePath])
            )

            if len(suggestions) != 0 {
                var err error
                f.suggestionHandler, err = tui.NewSuggestionsModel(currentFilePath, f.potentiallyFixableIssues[f.currentSuggestIndex].name, fmt.Sprintf("File %d of %d", f.currentFilePathIndex+1, len(f.filePaths)), suggestions)
                if err != nil {
                    f.Err = err

                    return f
                }

                f.currentSuggestIndex++

                return f
            }

            f.currentSuggestIndex++
        }

        f.currentFilePathIndex++
        f.currentSuggestIndex = 0
    }

    return f
}


The suggestion model:
package tui

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/atotto/clipboard"
    "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbles/textarea"
    tea "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea"
    stringdiff "github.com/pjkaufman/go-go-gadgets/pkg/string-diff"
)

type SuggestionsModel struct {
    file, group, fileStatus, OriginalText, FinalText string
    sectionSuggestionStates                          []suggestionState
    suggestionInput                                  textarea.Model
    currentSuggestIndex                              int
    Done, ChangeMade, replaceAll, editMode           bool
    Err                                              error
}

type suggestionState struct {
    isAccepted                                               bool
    original, originalSuggestion, currentSuggestion, display string
}

func NewSuggestionsModel(title, subtitle, fileStatus string, suggestions map[string]string) (SuggestionsModel, error) {
    ti := textarea.New()
    ti.Placeholder = "Enter an edited version of the original string"
    ti.CharLimit = 2000
    ti.ShowLineNumbers = false
    var (
        sectionSuggestionStates = make([]suggestionState, len(suggestions))
        i                       = 0
    )

    for original, suggestion := range suggestions {
        var display, err = getStringDiff(original, suggestion)
        if err != nil {
            return SuggestionsModel{}, err
        }

        sectionSuggestionStates[i] = suggestionState{
            original:           original,
            originalSuggestion: suggestion,
            currentSuggestion:  suggestion,
            display:            display,
        }

        i++
    }

    if len(sectionSuggestionStates) > 0 {
        ti.SetValue(sectionSuggestionStates[0].display)
    }

    return SuggestionsModel{
        suggestionInput:         ti,
        file:                    title,
        group:                   subtitle,
        fileStatus:              fileStatus,
        sectionSuggestionStates: sectionSuggestionStates,
    }, nil
}

func (f SuggestionsModel) Init() tea.Cmd {
    return nil
}

func (f SuggestionsModel) Update(msg tea.Msg) (SuggestionsModel, tea.Cmd) {
    if f.editMode {
        return f.handleEditKeys(msg)
    }

    return f.handleNonEditKeys(msg)
}

func (f SuggestionsModel) handleEditKeys(msg tea.Msg) (SuggestionsModel, tea.Cmd) {
    var (
        cmd               tea.Cmd
        err               error
        currentSuggestion suggestionState
    )

    if f.currentSuggestIndex+1 < len(f.sectionSuggestionStates) {
        currentSuggestion = f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex]
    }

    switch msg := msg.(type) {
    case tea.KeyMsg:
        switch msg.String() {
        case "ctrl+c":
            // TODO: populate this up without breaking the CLI
            f.Err = fmt.Errorf("User killed program")
            return f, nil
        case "esc":
            return f, tea.Quit
        case "ctrl+s":
            currentSuggestion.currentSuggestion = f.suggestionInput.Value()
            f.editMode = false

            f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex].display, err = getStringDiff(strings.TrimSpace(currentSuggestion.original), strings.TrimSpace(currentSuggestion.currentSuggestion))
            if err != nil {
                f.Err = err
                return f, nil
            }

            return f, nil
        case "ctrl+e":
            f.editMode = false

            f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex].display, err = getStringDiff(strings.TrimSpace(currentSuggestion.original), strings.TrimSpace(currentSuggestion.currentSuggestion))
            if err != nil {
                f.Err = err
                return f, nil
            }

            return f, nil
        case "ctrl+r":
            f.suggestionInput.SetValue(currentSuggestion.originalSuggestion)

            return f, nil
        }
    case tea.WindowSizeMsg:
        return f, tea.ClearScreen
    case error:
        f.Err = msg

        return f, nil
    }

    f.suggestionInput, cmd = f.suggestionInput.Update(msg)
    return f, cmd
}

func (f SuggestionsModel) handleNonEditKeys(msg tea.Msg) (SuggestionsModel, tea.Cmd) {
    var (
        cmd               tea.Cmd
        currentSuggestion suggestionState
    )

    if f.currentSuggestIndex+1 < len(f.sectionSuggestionStates) {
        currentSuggestion = f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex]
    }

    switch msg := msg.(type) {
    case tea.KeyMsg:
        switch msg.String() {
        case "ctrl+c":
            f.Err = fmt.Errorf("User killed program")
            return f, nil
        case "q", "esc":
            return f, tea.Quit
        case "e":
            if !currentSuggestion.isAccepted {
                f.editMode = true
                f.suggestionInput.SetValue(currentSuggestion.currentSuggestion)

                return f, nil
            }
        case "enter":
            if !currentSuggestion.isAccepted {
                var replaceCount = 1
                if f.replaceAll {
                    replaceCount = -1
                }

                f.FinalText = strings.Replace(f.FinalText, currentSuggestion.original, currentSuggestion.currentSuggestion, replaceCount)

                f.ChangeMade = true
                currentSuggestion.isAccepted = true
            }

            f = f.moveToNextSuggestion()

            return f, nil
        case "c":
            // Copy original value to the clipboard
            err := clipboard.WriteAll(currentSuggestion.original)
            if err != nil {
                f.Err = err
                return f, nil
            }

            return f, nil
        case "right", "l":
            f = f.moveToNextSuggestion()

            return f, nil

        case "left", "h":
            f = f.moveToPreviousSuggestion()

            return f, nil
        }
    case tea.WindowSizeMsg:
        return f, tea.ClearScreen
    case error:
        f.Err = msg

        return f, nil
    default:
        f.suggestionInput, cmd = f.suggestionInput.Update(msg)
    }

    return f, cmd
}

func (f SuggestionsModel) View() string {
    var s strings.Builder
    clearScreen(&s)

    if len(f.sectionSuggestionStates) == 0 {
        s.WriteString("No suggestions found")

        return s.String()
    }

    s.WriteString(titleStyle.Render(fmt.Sprintf("Current File: %s", f.file)) + "\n")
    s.WriteString(fileStatusStyle.Render(f.fileStatus))
    s.WriteString("\n")
    s.WriteString(groupStyle.Render(fmt.Sprintf("Issue Group: %s", f.group)) + "\n\n")

    if f.editMode {
        s.WriteString(f.suggestionInput.View())
    } else {
        s.WriteString(f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex].display)
    }

    s.WriteString("\n\n")

    s.WriteString("Suggestion ")
    s.WriteString(fmt.Sprint(f.currentSuggestIndex + 1))
    s.WriteString(" of ")
    s.WriteString(fmt.Sprint(len(f.sectionSuggestionStates)))
    s.WriteString(".\n\n")

    f.displaySuggestionControls(&s)

    // s.WriteString("\nOriginal:")
    // s.WriteString(f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex].original)
    // s.WriteString("\nOriginal Suggestion:")
    // s.WriteString(f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex].originalSuggestion)
    // s.WriteString("\nCurrent Suggestion:")
    // s.WriteString(f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex].currentSuggestion)
    // s.WriteString("\nDisplay Value:")
    // s.WriteString(f.suggestionInput.Value())

    return s.String()
}

func (f SuggestionsModel) displaySuggestionControls(s *strings.Builder) {
    s.WriteString(groupStyle.Render("Controls:") + "\n")

    if !f.editMode {
        s.WriteString("← / → : Previous/Next Suggestion   ")
        s.WriteString("E: Edit   ")
        s.WriteString("C: Copy   ")
        s.WriteString("Enter: Accept   ")
        s.WriteString("Q/Esc: Quit")
    } else {
        s.WriteString("Ctrl+R: Reset   ")
        s.WriteString("Ctrl+E: Cancel edit   ")
        s.WriteString("Ctrl+S: Accept   ")
        s.WriteString("Esc: Quit")
        s.WriteString("Ctrl+C: Exit without saving\n")
    }
}

func (f SuggestionsModel) moveToNextSuggestion() SuggestionsModel {
    // TODO: determine how to tell if th user accidentally tried to move to the next suggestion on the last one or if they actually wanted them reset.
    if f.currentSuggestIndex+1 < len(f.sectionSuggestionStates) {
        f.currentSuggestIndex++
        f.suggestionInput.SetValue(f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex].display)
    } else {
        f.Done = true
    }

    return f
}

func (f SuggestionsModel) moveToPreviousSuggestion() SuggestionsModel {
    if f.currentSuggestIndex > 0 {
        f.currentSuggestIndex--
        f.suggestionInput.SetValue(f.sectionSuggestionStates[f.currentSuggestIndex].display)
    }

    return f
}

func getStringDiff(original, new string) (string, error) {
    return stringdiff.GetPrettyDiffString(strings.TrimLeft(original, "\n"), strings.TrimLeft(new, "\n"))
}


The section break model:
package tui

import (
    "strings"

    "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbles/textinput"
    tea "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea"
)

type SectionBreakModel struct {
    sectionBreakInput textinput.Model
    sectionBreak      string
    Done              bool
    Err               error
}

func NewSectionBreakModel() SectionBreakModel {
    ti := textinput.New()
    ti.Placeholder = "Section Break"
    ti.Focus()
    ti.CharLimit = 100
    ti.Width = 20

    return SectionBreakModel{
        sectionBreakInput: ti,
    }
}

func (f SectionBreakModel) Init() tea.Cmd {
    return nil
}

func (f SectionBreakModel) Update(msg tea.Msg) (SectionBreakModel, tea.Cmd) {
    var cmd tea.Cmd

    switch msg := msg.(type) {
    case tea.KeyMsg:
        switch msg.Type {
        case tea.KeyEnter:
            f.sectionBreak = f.sectionBreakInput.Value()

            if strings.TrimSpace(f.sectionBreak) != "" {
                f.Done = true
            }
        case tea.KeyCtrlC, tea.KeyEsc:
            return f, tea.Quit
        }
    case tea.WindowSizeMsg:
        return f, tea.ClearScreen
    case error:
        f.Err = msg

        return f, nil
    }

    f.sectionBreakInput, cmd = f.sectionBreakInput.Update(msg)
    return f, cmd
}

func (f SectionBreakModel) View() string {
    var s strings.Builder
    clearScreen(&s)

    s.WriteString("What is the section break for the epub?\n\n")
    s.WriteString(f.sectionBreakInput.View())
    s.WriteString("\n\n")

    f.displaySectionBreakControls(&s)

    return s.String()
}

func (f SectionBreakModel) displaySectionBreakControls(s *strings.Builder) {
    s.WriteString(groupStyle.Render("Controls:") + "\n")
    s.WriteString("Enter: Continue   Ctrl+C/Esc: Quit\n")
}

func (f SectionBreakModel) Value() string {
    return f.sectionBreak
}


The pretty diff strings which seem to get cut off sometimes by the TUI, but not the CLI version:
package stringdiff

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/andreyvit/diff"
    "github.com/fatih/color"
)

var (
    red   = color.New(color.BgRed, color.FgBlack).SprintFunc()
    green = color.New(color.BgGreen, color.FgBlack).SprintFunc()
)

// GetPrettyDiffString gets the diff string of the 2 passed in values where removals have a red background and additions have a green background
func GetPrettyDiffString(original, new string) (string, error) {
    diffString := diff.CharacterDiff(original, new)

    var buff bytes.Buffer
    var diffsLen = len(diffString)
    var char, nextChar, nextNextChar, section string
    var inSection bool
    for i := 0; i < len(diffString); {
        char = string(diffString[i])
        if char == "(" && i+2 < diffsLen && !inSection {
            nextChar = string(diffString[i+1])
            nextNextChar = string(diffString[i+2])
            if nextChar == "+" && nextNextChar == "+" {
                inSection = true

                i += 3
                continue
            } else if nextChar == "~" && nextNextChar == "~" {
                inSection = true

                i += 3
                continue
            }
        } else if char == "~" && i+2 < diffsLen && string(diffString[i+1]) == "~" && string(diffString[i+2]) == ")" {
            inSection = false
            buff.WriteString(red(section))
            section = ""

            i += 3
            continue
        } else if char == "+" && i+2 < diffsLen && string(diffString[i+1]) == "+" && string(diffString[i+2]) == ")" {
            inSection = false
            buff.WriteString(green(section))
            section = ""

            i += 3
            continue
        }

        if inSection {
            section += char
        } else {
            buff.WriteString(char)
        }

        i++
    }

    displayString, err := repairLatin1(buff.String())
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf(`failed to correct any latin1 bad characters: %w`, err)
    }

    return displayString, nil
}

// From https://go.dev/play/p/dBrx_ZmrsMN and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510458/golang-convert-iso8859-1-to-utf8
// It seems that the latin1 text was not encoded correctly so we needed to look for any characters that were garbled and go
// ahead and fix those specific characters.
func repairLatin1(s string) (string, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, 0, len(s))
    for i, r := range s {
        if r > 255 {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("character %q at index %d is not part of latin1", string(r), i)
        }
        buf = append(buf, byte(r))
    }
    return string(buf), nil
}


Here area couple of examples of what I am seeing that looks to be incorrectly printed values from the View:

Two instances of Suggestion # of #, but only 1 instance of that value being printed in the code here. This could be related to the fact that I treat this component as disposable after each set of suggestions, but that seems a bit odd if that were the case.


The controls and other text disappear for some reason. The controls should always be printed from my understanding. (Partially fixed by wordwrap. You can see the group is missing in this image and it is also still missing after the wordwrap)


The suggested text gets cut off mid-string with no clear reason why. It is possible that this is just a bad file I am pointing to, but when I ran through the same logic using just the CLI I never encountered text that was broken apart like this. (Fixed by wordwrap)



Steps to reproduce:

Clone the repo listed above
Run Make install
Run ebook-lint epub fixable -a -u -f ./ebook-lint/cmd/epub/testdata/original/jules-verne_from-the-earth-to-the-moon_ward-lock-co.epub from the base of the repository
Enter any non-whitespace value for the section break value, then just keep tapping the right arrow keys until the weird display values show up.

Edit:
It seems that the controls and suggestion text in the center displaying weird/cutting off mid sentence was due to needing to manually word wrap the suggestion text. I have done that and those two issues seem to be mostly gone, but they seem to show up every once in a while when other elements disappear. But the issue with the group name disappearing still occurs. The latest changes can be found here.
